# Saving changes in Activity after going to another Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I have a `Button` in `FirstActivity.java` which when you press leads you to a second activity: `SecondActivity.java`, which has another button `BackButton` that leads you back to `FirstActivity.java`. The code in the first activity allows you to change the layout according to different conditions. Is there a way that if the layout of `FirstActivity.java` is changed, you press the `Button` to go to the second activity, then when you press the `BackButton` to go back to `FirstActivity.java`, the layout changes will be saved in the first activity?

Comment: provide code for how you start SecondActivity from FirstActivity

Comment: ` Button Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
            }
        });
`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950286/save-a-activity-in-android-when-moved-to-another-activity

Answer (score 0):

You can use putExtra for send data to SecondActivity, and return data to onActivityResult.